# How to open web page in browser from android apk?

Tags: android, browser, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I created a simple app with Sencha Architect and pack it to .apk.
When I test it on my device, i notice that I couldn't switch to browser and open a web page from the app. 
(e.g. the app show a yes-no dialog, when user press the yes button it should switch to browser and open certain url)

Here is the code that I use:

```
Ext.Msg.confirm(
        "Confirmation", // Title
        "Please tap yes to google in web browser.", // Message
        function (btn) {
            if (btn === 'yes') {
                //Ext.Msg.alert("You have selected Yes", "");
                // This should opening the web page on that can be used to connect to facebook from server //
                Ext.device.Device.openURL('http://www.google.com');
            }
            else {
                //Ext.Msg.alert("NO", "You have selected NO");
            }
        },
        this
        );
```

It working when I tested it in a browser, but not working when I packed it to apk with sencha cmd. Does anyone can help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has some issues in the version 2.1B2.

```
This will work with the next version of the Native Packager which is going in with Beta 3.    -
Jamie Avins  
Sencha - Sencha Touch Dev Team
```

[Link to Forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?236532-2.1B2-Ext.device.Device.openURL-doesn-t-seem-to-work)

Comment: so we have to upgrade sencha cmd or sencha ?

Comment: @MayurHow can I build app with sencha sdk tools?

Comment: use phonegap. here is a tut http://andidog.de/blog/2012/06/packaging-a-sencha-touch-2-application-with-phonegap-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

I think that mistake is there:
If (btn = = = yes), there is not === but == . Try it..